# Can't connect to my localhost with Volley to my Symfony2 api

Tags: php, android, json, symfony, android-volley

I'm actually trying to do a simply GET request using Volley to my Symfony2 api hosted in my pc, first I tried some tutorials getting the JSON from here http://httpbin.org/get?site=code&network=tutsplus and it worked pretty well... Then I started trying to get the JSON from my api but I get some errors and I cant figure why, here is the log:

```
       10-07 16:15:54.456 24582-24582/? W/System.err: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.44 (port 80) after 2500ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
10-07 16:15:54.456 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:151)
10-07 16:15:54.466 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
10-07 16:15:54.466 24582-24582/? W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.44 (port 80) after 2500ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
10-07 16:15:54.466 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
10-07 16:15:54.466 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:161)
10-07 16:15:54.466 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
10-07 16:15:54.466 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
10-07 16:15:54.466 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
10-07 16:15:54.466 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
10-07 16:15:54.466 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:152)
10-07 16:15:54.466 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
10-07 16:15:54.466 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
10-07 16:15:54.466 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
10-07 16:15:54.466 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
10-07 16:15:54.466 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
10-07 16:15:54.466 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
10-07 16:15:54.466 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
10-07 16:15:54.476 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:110)
10-07 16:15:54.476 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
10-07 16:15:54.476 24582-24582/? W/System.err:  ... 1 more
10-07 16:15:54.476 24582-24582/? W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
10-07 16:15:54.476 24582-24582/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:208)
```

The request is as simple as:

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
String url = "http://192.168.1.44/api/fincas/1";

final JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                // the response is already constructed as a JSONObject!
                System.out.println(response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

My AndroidManifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alvaro.pruebarequests">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the JSON it should get is `[{"id":1,"irrigation_type":"type","plant_variety":"variety","hand_number":722,"born_register":"2005-05-05T00:00:00+0000"}]`

Im very frustated with this, since I couldn't fix it...

Comment: Where is your app running on?

Comment: On my phone with the debug mode activated, connected by usb and in the same network too

Comment: Have you checked if the firewall prevents connection? Switch it off for a test.

Comment: Yeah, after a few tries I switched it off, but I'm getting the same error

Comment: Then check in Symphony settings if it is bound to serve only for localhost/127.0.0.1.

Comment: Already tried to connect via browser in another PC in the same network with my ip (192.168.1.x) and it works, I can see my JSON in the web browser... But I can't get this working in AndroidStudio

Comment: ' HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xadbcfaa0, tid 3251
10-07 23:43:31.761 2928-3251/com.example.alvaro.pruebarequests I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-07 23:43:31.993 2928-2934/com.example.alvaro.pruebarequests W/art: Suspending all threads took: 41.080ms '

Comment: 10-07 23:43:38.263 2928-2928/com.example.alvaro.pruebarequests W/System.err: com.android.volley.TimeoutError
10-07 23:43:38.263 2928-2928/com.example.alvaro.pruebarequests W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:141)
10-07 23:43:38.263 2928-2928/com.example.alvaro.pruebarequests W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)

Comment: That's what I'm getting atm

Comment: Try with a browser on your Android device.

Comment: `But I can't get this working in AndroidStudio`. ???? That is nonsense. Android Studio has nothing to do with it. You can't get it working on your Android device.

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`. That is a strange place where you put that. Normally it would be in the top lines of onCreate().

Comment: Yeah noticed that, I already changed it but had no effect, Still can't get this request work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I Figured out the solution, I was missing the header "Accept json", if somebody is having this problem, here is how to fix it :) just add that header

Answer (score 0):

How does the webserver run?

With embed php server, nginx, apache, other web server? (what is the vhost conf)

Comment: I run it with "php app/console server:run" with Symfony

Comment: Local server for the moment

Comment: if you want an external access to your dev server you need to specify the ipaddress of your computer :
php app/console server:run <ip>:<a_port>
where 
<ip> is your local ip address
<port> is a free port of your computer